# ip address use error 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

windows 8 app c# i get error  A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

the code example is in google drive

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B75nbNO58O7dN1BNMzFTZGQtdVU/edit?usp=sharing

and instead of 10.0.0.52 i use bing.com the output is correct no exception please help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There might be problems in your web service. It is not accessible. It seems to be local web service, not Internet web service.

Comment: s its local web service only k is the code is right eh xyroid

Comment: and instead of 10.0.0.52 i use bing.com the output is correct no exception please help

Comment: What's the use of service ? Are you using it as authentication purpose ? Try to open 10.0.0.52 url in web browser, check whether it's working or not.

Comment: farhan ip address not working but web address alone working please help

Comment: Try to add Private Network capability in manifest and then run the app. http://i.imgur.com/OIk54V9.png

Comment: farhan your awesome it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[hover this message see image and select the ticks in the image in your app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TAkU.png)